# Safe recursive delete in bash

Tags: linux, bash, validation, delete-file

Is there a way to check if the supplied path either by user input or some self-detect-mechanism safe to be deleted in bash scripting?

For example:

```
rm -rf $SOMELOCATION
```

Obviously I don't want SOMELOCATION to be any of / /var /etc /home /usr /opt /root or some important directories.

Is there a way to prevent such **incident** in bash without iterating all those directory above (and possibly more important directory)?

Is there something like isSystemDirectory function return true or false? :-)

Comment: In Linux, you can't delete system files unless you are `root`. As long as you don't run `rm` as `sudo`, you don't need to worry about the user deleting files that are not owned by him/her.

Comment: SO is for computer programming questions. Unix tech support belongs in unix.SE or SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you need to check the value of `SOMELOCATION` before you use it as the argument to `rm`.

```
case $SOMELOCATION of
  /|/var|/etc|/home|/usr|/opt|/root) echo "Will not delete $SOMELOCATION" ;;
  *) rm -rf "$SOMELOCATION ;;
esac
```

Permissions allow `rm` to fail, but since `root` essentially has permission to do *anything*, it is simply up to you to take appropriate care when running any command as `root`. (Or at the very least, to have an up-to-date backup available to recover from a mistake.)